# c# Bind datatable to chart. Column based. Error :index was out of range

Tags: c#, charts, datatable, datasource

I've got datatable and want to use it for chart. here's the code and error in the end.

```
 dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);     


        chart1.Series.Clear();         

        chart1.DataSource = dt;            
        chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Id";    <-------- ERROR HERE
        chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "SerialNo";  
        chart1.DataBind();
```

Error : Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

dt content:

```
[Id]      [Uname]   [SerialNo]
2154      Rauno3     1234
2155      Rauno3     1245
...        ...       ...
```

What am I missing ?
Thanks !

Comment: You are missing the Series you just cleared!

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding columns to your Datatable

```
dt = new DataTable();//Create new Datatable

chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Id";// refer to column which is not there
```

Add this line before you use columns to fix the error

```
dt.ColumnCount = 3;
```

I can see that in your dt content you are getting 3 column but you declaring only two in your code

Answer (score 0):

Simply setting the DataSource doesn't create the Series collection.
(And, on any case, you have Clear'ed them)
You need to add a new Series to your collection

```
chart1.Series.Add("MySeries");
chart1.Series["MySeries"].XValueMember = "Id";
chart1.Series["MySeries"].YValueMembers = "SerialNo";
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, Thought the chart was already added when done in the chart properties

Comment: ah ok Yeh.. Wanted to clear the data content but didnt know it clears the added series also :) . anyways- thanks :) works perfect now !